# If Charles Xavier wore Magneto's helmet, would it block Charles from using his abilities?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Normally the helmet is used to keep telepaths **out** of your head. Would the helmet work in reverse: when a telepath wears it, their abilities can't affect anyone?

I tried searching for the answer to this and the only relevant thing I found was an old [thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/2e58q1/xmen_if_prof_x_wears_magnetos_helmet_can_he_use/), but no actual answer.

Answer (score 6):

In New X-men #137 Kid Omega uses a copy of Magneto's helmet to suppress Professor X's abilities[image].

Answer (score -1):

During Astonishing X-men Vol.3 #44-47, a weird NO-BALDER Prof.X from another dimension captured 616's Cyclops...He wanted him to run some creepy Engine so that they could get energy again and Cyclops would die too...Sounds terrible, huh~
So Cyclops started a violent revolution with other prisoners: a GAY-Wolverine, a TEEN-Nightcrawler, a Mrs.SUMMERS-Emma. Finally the TEEN-Nightcrawler send a Magneto's Helmet on EVIL-HAIRY-Xavier’s head... Well~That's how the evil Xavier failed...
Absolutely it would works on 616/Prime Earth, I think.

Comment: Can you offer a panel showing these events?

Comment: I think 'NO-BALDER Prof.X from another dimension' is Savior http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Xavier_(Earth-12245) but I can't find a description or panel of the events described

Comment: I'm pretty sure that during Morrison's New X-Men Run, the "Riot at Xavier's" arc, Quentin Quire and his group also put a helmet to keep Xavier from calling help after they abducted him... I don't think it was SPECIFICALLY Magneto's, but I *think* they said it was based on his.